# Regex to require one alphabet and one non-alphabet and no whitespace

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex in Java to match at least 1 alphabet and 1 non-alphabet (could be anything except A-Za-z) and no white space.

Below Regex is working partially correct:

```
^([A-Za-z]{1,}[^A-Za-z]{1,})+$
```

It matches aaaa7777
but doesn't match 777aaaaa.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `"(?s)^(?=\\P{Alpha}*\\p{Alpha})(?=\\p{Alpha}*\\P{Alpha}).+$"`

Comment: I'm sorry but what's \\P{Alpha}?

Comment: `\p{Alpha}` matches letters, `\P{Alpha}` matches non-letters.

Comment: It's not working. I tested at https://www.regextester.com/95560

Comment: Test in Java if you have trouble using online testers. Testing a Java regex in a JS regex tester makes little sense since the regex engines are very different. I provided the Java solution as per the question tag.

Comment: ad [@sweeper's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59355501/5527985), I think you could even optimize it a bit [like this](https://regex101.com/r/iE5K0Y/3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex implicitly assumes the order of the characters you want to match. The regex is saying that a letter *must come before* a non-latter. However, you want the letter and the non-letter to come in either order, so you need to account for both cases. Also note that it should be `[^\sa-zA-Z]` instead of `[^a-zA-Z]` as you don't allow spaces.

```
(?:[a-zA-Z][^\sa-zA-Z]|[^\sa-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])
```

At the start and end, any non-space character is allowed, so:

```
^\S*(?:[a-zA-Z][^\sa-zA-Z]|[^\sa-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])\S*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
s.matches("(?=\\P{Alpha}*\\p{Alpha})(?=\\p{Alpha}*\\P{Alpha})\\S*")
```

[This is how the pattern works](https://regex101.com/r/fmU89u/1).

**Details**

- The pattern will match a whole string since `^` and `\z` anchors are implicit in `matches`
- `(?=\P{Alpha}*\p{Alpha})` - a lookahead that requires at least one ASCII letter after any 0+ chars other than an ASCII letter
- `(?=\p{Alpha}*\P{Alpha})` - a lookahead that requires a char other than an ASCII letter after 0 or more ASCII letters
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars.

To make the regex Unicode aware replace `\p{Alpha}` with `\p{L}` and `\P{Alpha}` with `\P{L}`.

Comment: @Abhishek I have just noticed you wanted to match a string that has no whitespace. I updated the answer to account for that. The previous variant that allows any chars in the string is in the [answer history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59355448/1).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't the right tool for this type of validation. Just write out the plain logic, your specific example:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("'foo' ? " + doesMatch("foo"));
        System.out.println("'bar7' ? " + doesMatch("bar7"));
        System.out.println("'55baz' ? " + doesMatch("55baz"));
    }

    public static boolean doesMatch(String input) {
        boolean hasAlpha = false,
                hasNonAlpha = false;

        for(char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
                hasAlpha = true;
            } else {
                hasNonAlpha = true;
            }

            if(hasAlpha && hasNonAlpha) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Anyone can understand what inputs do match and which inputs don't. If you use regular expressions this wouldn't be so simple.